# How to format HTML/CSS to align with single word in sentence?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how to refer to what I need to do. So here is an example of the formatting.

```
Where ABC is the Actual Before Calculation
        A is the total population of the US
      XYB is the percentage that own their own homes
      XYC is the percentage in a rural area
```

Notice how all the sentences are aligned with the word `is`. It's kind of a smart indenting, for lack of a better term. You have the right term, then please enlighten me.

I've not found an HTML/CSS page that does this, but I have seen it in print. Or would PHP be needed to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Post the HTML and CSS you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **[Definition List](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp)** for this:

**HTML**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Where ABC is</dt>
    <dd>the Actual Before Calculation</dd>
    <dt>A is</dt>
    <dd>the total population of the US</dd>
    <dt>XYB is</dt>
    <dd>the percentage that own their own homes</dd>
    <dt>XYC is</dt>
    <dd>the percentage in a rural area</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
dl {
    border: 3px double #ccc;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
dd {
    margin: 0 0 0 145px;
    padding: 0 0 0.5em 0;
    min-height: 1em;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6KaML/5/)**

Comment: @ChiRow if there is a `<dd>` element with nothing in it creates a layout issue. `clear: left;` fixes this.

Comment: @AfromanJ, I see the reason for clear: left.  That makes sense.  However, it looks like one would also need height: 1em; in the dd section to keep it all lined up if a dd is empty.

Comment: @ChiRow good spot i'll update my answer with `min-height: 1em;` for the `<dd>` element.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you http://jsfiddle.net/Ytv8p/1/

HTML

```
<div> <span class="a">Where ABC</span>
 <span>is</span>
 <span>the Actual Before Calculation.</span>

</div>
<div> <span class="a">A</span>
 <span>is</span>
 <span>the total population of the US</span>

</div>
<div> <span class="a">XYB</span>
 <span>is</span>
 <span>the percentage that own their own homes</span>

</div>
<div> <span class="a">XYC</span>
 <span>is</span>
 <span>the percentage in a rural area</span>

</div>
```

CSS

```
span {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 2px;
}
.a {
    width:80px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Simple.  Not to many moving parts.  Easily scalable!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table, I did a quick JSFiddle:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Where ABC is</td>
    <td>the Actual Before Calculation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Where A is</td>
    <td>the total population of the US</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6fr5/1/)

With some CSS you can align the text of the first `td` on the right:

```
td:first-of-type {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have various solutions. Here's one building a `table` from your unformatted text using jQuery :

```
var lines = $('#a').text().split('\n');
$t = $('<table>').appendTo($('#a').empty());
lines.forEach(function(l){
  var m = l.match(/(.*)( is )(.*)/);
  if (m) $t.append('<tr><td>'+m[1]+'</td><td>'+m[2]+'</td><td>'+m[3]+'</td></tr>');
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/IcArufIR/4/)

EDIT : I understood the question as the need to start from a not formatted text. If you can do the formatting by hand, disregard this answer.

Comment: I don't understand, why have you answered this question using JQuery?

Comment: Because it's a sane solution to make the transformation from an unformated text. I forgot to precise "using jQuery". But as you get upvoted I suppose everybody's else thought the question was trivial and that OP already had some formatted content.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but it doesn't indent the start of the text. It leaves a gap between the first word and "is".

Comment: Ok fair enough, maybe you could use a Definition List instead of table in your answer too.

Comment: @Edward That's just a matter of `td:first-child { text-align:right}`.